# OpenGL and GLUT/ C++ Odd texture looping issue

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glut, glu

I am working with textures in OpenGL and have came across a strange issue. Sometimes an image that's loaded in is pushed over to the right slightly. I will supply code and screen shots below.

[image]

```
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SOIL.h>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 512;

GLuint Tex;
GLuint Tex2;

GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename, int w, int h )
{
    GLuint texture;
    int width, height;
    unsigned char * data;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );

    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
    width = w;
    height = h;
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3);
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST );

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
    free( data );

    return texture;
}

void Reshape( int width, int height )
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );

    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0.0f, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0f, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 1.0f, 100.0f );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}

void lightInit( void )
{
    GLfloat lightWhite[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightBlack[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, lightWhite );
    glMaterialf( GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 30 );

    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightBlack );
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightWhite );
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightWhite );
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos );

    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
}

void drawTexObj()
{
    Tex = LoadTexture( "texture2.bmp", 1024, 512 );
    if( Tex == 0 )
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glPushAttrib( GL_CURRENT_BIT );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glVertex2f( 0.0f, 512.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 1.0f );
        glVertex2f( 1024.0f, 512.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 0.0f );
        glVertex2f( 1024.0f, 0.0f );
    glEnd();
    glPopAttrib();
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glDeleteTextures( (GLsizei)1, &Tex );
}

void drawTexObj2()
{
    Tex2 = LoadTexture( "texture.bmp", 1024, 512 );
    if( Tex2 == 0 )
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glVertex2f( 0.0f, 0.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glVertex2f( 0.0f, 256.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 1.0f );
        glVertex2f( 512.0f, 256.0f );

        glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 0.0f );
        glVertex2f( 512.0f, 0.0f );

    glEnd();
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glDeleteTextures( (GLsizei)1, &Tex2 );
}

void Display()
{
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f );

    drawTexObj();
    drawTexObj2();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH );

    glutInitWindowPosition( 200, 100 );
    glutInitWindowSize( 1024, 512 );

    glutCreateWindow( "Texturing :D!" );

    //lightInit();

    glutDisplayFunc( Display );
    glutIdleFunc( Display );
    glutReshapeFunc( Reshape );

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Why `#include` SOIL if you aren't using it?

Comment: My first intuition says it has something to do with GL_DEPTH and/or GL_REPEAT

Comment: You are actually loading and deleting the texture every frame? That would be the *first* thing I would fix.

Comment: Yeah, I must say that this is not neat code what so ever. It's simply to see if I can get it working. The SOIL include was because, I was slipping in and out of using it. Just a little mistake :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with reading the file in the first place.  BMP files are not simple neat arrays of pixel bytes, so you can't just read in width*height*3 bytes.  You will see the image data in there, (assuming 24 bpp storage), but there is also header information which will push the pixel data over on the display.  I'm surprised that the 2nd bitmap looks OK, although this might be coincidence that the header matches the image width.

A better solution would be to use the Gdi to load the images...

```
GdiplusStartupInput lstartup_input;
GdiplusStartupOutput lstartup_output;
ULONG_PTR   ltoken;

GdiplusStartup(&ltoken, &lstartup_input, &lstartup_output);

Bitmap *lbitmap;
lbitmap = new Bitmap(wszPath);

GdiplusShutdown(ltoken);

RGBQUAD *pBits = (RGBQUAD *) malloc(lbitmap->GetWidth() * lbitmap->GetHeight() * 4 * sizeof(BYTE));
lbitmapdata.Scan0 = pBits;
lbitmapdata.Width = lbitmap->GetWidth();
lbitmapdata.Height = lbitmap->GetHeight();
lbitmapdata.PixelFormat = PixelFormat32bppARGB;
lbitmapdata.Stride = lbitmap->GetWidth()*4;

Rect    lrect(0,0,lbitmap->GetWidth(), lbitmap->GetHeight());
st = lbitmap->LockBits(&lrect, ImageLockModeUserInputBuf | ImageLockModeRead,
    PixelFormat32bppARGB, &lbitmapdata);
ASSERT(st == Ok);
st = lbitmap->UnlockBits(&lbitmapdata); // Unlock straightaway, because we just want to extract the pixel data
ASSERT(st == Ok);
```

This snipped uses 4 bytes per-pixel, as I use the alpha channel, but from there you should be able to convert it as you need it.  Here's a code snippet to convert the BGRA to RGB.  (You could change the pixel format for UnlockBits to PixelFormat24bppRGB, but you might still need to swap the colours about - try it and see.)

```
BYTE *rgbBits = (malloc lbitmap->GetHeight() * lbitmap->GetWidth() * 3);
BYTE *rgbPtr = rgbBits;
pPixel = (RGBQUAD *)m_pBits;
for (li = 0; li < lbitmap->GetHeight() * lbitmap->GetWidth(); li++)
{
    *(rgbPtr++) = pPixel->rgbRed;
    *(rgbPtr++) = pPixel->rgbGreen;
    *(rgbPtr++) = pPixel->rgbBlue;
    pPixel++;
}
```

(Note that I just pulled this code out of my project, so it might need some cleaning up.  Let me know.)

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help! I have decided to move to libpng for loading my images, although I will consider this. If you could help me out one more bit, what are the advantages of BMP's over PNG's? Faster loading? Smaller files? Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DavidBittner: BMPs have **zero** advantage over PNGs from a technical point of view. Writing a BMP file loader (independent from the GDI) is rather simple, but that's about it. If you can use PNGs, use them.

Comment: Another image library you might consider is stb_image (http://nothings.org/stb_image.c). It's a single source file with no dependencies. It does have some limitations, but you'll be able to load most of the common file formats, and I think it's a bit easier to use than libpng

Comment: Might as well make sure to support the most common formats while you are at it. I would guess that might even be simpler since using libpng requires a bit more effort to understand.

Comment: Yes, I looked at a lot of solutions, and went with GDIplus in the end, because is supports the main common formats of BMP, PNG, GIF and JPG.  There might be more recent ways to do this, but for a general solution, I would certainly recommend going with something that supports multiple formats.

Comment: As for BMP, its really not used much anymore.  PNG (lossless compression) and JPG (lossy compression) are the formats of choice these days, mainly for their much smaller file size.

Comment: Thanks everybody! Didn't expect this much of a response! I will consider everything you guys sent. Thanks a lot for the help!